# Intershop ICM // Invalidate Session

Tags: intershop

I want to invalidate a session completely:

- delete the session on the application server
- reset the session ID on the web adapter

**Question**: What is the best way to do this?

My current idea is to delete the sid cookie and use the `SessionMgrImpl:removeSession` and `SessionMgrImpl:removeSessionState` methods to get rid of the old session data.

**Update**

Of course you don't want to delete the sid since there might be other sessions on the server which needs to stay active like a back office session. So resetting the webadapter session is not a good idea.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I want to force a session recreate and a session invalidation for the old one if somebody logs out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, SessionMgrImpl:removeSession should work. It is also used in Method checkSessionTimeout.

```
    Enumeration<Session> en = sessionTable.getExpiredSessions(count);

    while (en.hasMoreElements())
    {
        Session session = en.nextElement();
        removeSession(session);
    }
```

Comment: Does it make sense to call SessionMgrImpl:removeSessionState  in addition?